# Order large numbers that are saved as a varchar

Tags: mysql, order-by

An unsigned bigint is the maximum int size in mysql as far as I'm aware. So for good measure I'm using varchar(255) since some values in my db are larger than an unsigned bigint.

I'm looking to order them though as if they were an int though. Is this possible?

Example:
999,1000,1001

Ordering this by Int goes 999,1000,1001 or 1001,1000,999

Ordering this by varchar goes
1000,1001,999 or 999,1001,1000

Since sorting via varchar compares a string one at a time

I’m wondering if it’s possible to store it via varchar but sort like an int

Comment: Could you please provide some example numbers?

Comment: @J.D. hey JD, I’ve updated the question. Let me know if this helps and/or if I should be more specific. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you should use `varbinary` instead? Then store it in hexadecimal `0x03e8` is 1000. Sorting will then just work

Comment: You can use the `DECIMAL` data type, specifying a precision up to 65 digits, and a scale from 0 to 30 digits after the decimal. Do you really need to support up to 255 digit integers? Or would 65 digits of `DECIMAL(65,0)` suffice?

Comment: All you need is leading `'0'`s.

Comment: Please explain the use case.  That is, what do these numbers represent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If all the values are positive integers and they never have leading 0s, you could try the following sorting method:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  MyTableOfBigNumbers
ORDER BY
  CHAR_LENGTH(IntegerStringColumn) ASC
, IntegerStringColumn              ASC
;
```

This way shorter string literals will correctly go before longer ones, as should be expected.  Numbers with the identical number of digits will be sorted based on your active collation, which I hope already sorts the numerals in the sane way (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9).

To reverse the sorting direction, just replace `ASC` with `DESC`:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  MyTableOfBigNumbers
ORDER BY
  CHAR_LENGTH(IntegerStringColumn) DESC
, IntegerStringColumn              DESC
;
```

Comment: The collation for that column may as well be `ascii_bin`.  Do not store leading zeros, it will mess up the `ORDER BY`.  If the table is big, the Optimizer will necessarily scan the entire table when doing a range test.

Answer (score 3):

`BIGINT UNSIGNED` tops out at about 19 digits, and keeps precision down to "1".

Consider `FLOAT`.  It tops out at about 38 digits, but has precision of only about 7 digits.  (And it takes only 4 bytes to store).

Or `DOUBLE` -- 308 digits, 16 precision.  8 bytes.

Or (as already mentioned) `DECIMAL(65,0)` -- 65, 65, 29 bytes.

Yet another idea... Both a `VARCHAR` and a `DOUBLE`.  Use the `VARCHAR` for storing a very long string of digits and `DOUBLE` for ordering and sorting.  (Flaw:  Two numbers with the same first 16 digits may sort incorrectly; can you live with that?)

`VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin` -- 255, 255, <=256

`TEXT CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin` -- 65535, 65535, <=65537

`MEDIUMTEXT CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin` -- ~16M-1, ~16M, <=16M+3

Consider `INT UNSIGNED`, etc.  That gives one extra a bit's worth of range for each of the *INT types, over the default of `SIGNED`.  (`UNSIGNED` is irrelevant or unnecessary for the other datatypes.)

Answer (score 0):

> An unsigned bigint is the maximum int size in mysql as far as I'm aware. So for good measure I'm using varchar(255) since some values in my db are larger than an unsigned bigint.

You're storing *255 digit* numbers?  Forgive me, but I don't think so.

> 999,1000,1001

That *doesn't* look like a decimal number to me (although 99,910,001,001 *would*).
That looks *to me* like an **array** of [three] decimal numbers stored in the *same field*.
That's a Bad Idea, as you've discovered.

Split these out into a [sub-]table with the primary key of the original record, plus this new value.

```
select * 
from main_table ; 

+----+
| pk | 
+----+
| 77 | 
+----+

select * 
from sub_table ; 

+----+-------+
| pk | value |
+----+-------+
| 77 |   999 |
| 77 |  1000 |
| 77 |  1001 |
+----+-------+
```

Then you can do *integer* sorting on a proper, **Integer** field.

To paraphrase one Montgomery Scott:

> "Always use the Right **Data Type** for the Right Job".

Comment: I think you missed the Point. With 999,1000,1001 OP means that there are three rows, each with one number and this is how they are sorted.

Comment: If there are three rows, each with a number, then they will be sorted as numbers.  
If there are three rows, each with a string, then they will be sorted as strings.
If the OP wants things sorted as numbers, then they need to be stored as numbers. 
 Period.  
Implicit Type Coercion has some nasty side-effects, not least of which it slows everything down.

Comment: OP has realized that, too. But the regular integer fields don't work for them, so they are asking what else to do. But as it stands this post answers a question that hasn't been asked.

Comment: Personally, I'm still not convinced that the O.P. is /actually/ trying to store numbers that are more than 20 digits in length (BitInt's top out at 2^64, which is about 1.8x10^19) but, if that really /is/ the case, then zero-padding each value is probably their only other solution.  Floating Point Data Types can handle the numerical /size/ that they require, but not necessarily the integral granularity of their Requirement.